# Cannot get Roblox player attribute value

Tags: roblox

```lua
script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function(player)
    print("TOUCHED")
    if player:GetAttribute("Hiding") then
        print("tag player touch????")
    else
        print("HMM")

    end
end)
```

This should detect if a player, not a character, has the tag. I KNOW that the player has the tag.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Im trying to check if the player has a certain attribute set by another script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the `.Touched` event fires, it sends the workspace part that caused the collision as an argument to your custom `.Touched` event handler. You are calling GetAttribute on this part, which is contained inside the character. Instead, go up the parent heirarchy ( `touchedPart.Parent.Parent...` ) until you arrive at the character model.

To find the player from the character, use

```lua
local PlayerService = game:GetService("Players")
local player = PlayerService:GetPlayerFromCharacter( character )
```

You can find more information here: https://create.roblox.com/docs/building-and-visuals/physics/detecting-collisions